# How to get a value for admin css color either gray or blue

Tags: css, theme-options

I want implement theme option which will have two css files.

Example, if current admin set their profile to blue color I want load blue css for the theme options.

```
if (current-value-css-admin)
  load blue
else 
  load gray
```

Let me know how do I get current data for the wp admin color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be retrieved with `$color = get_user_option('admin_color');`, just don't forget to check for empty return and default to something in that case.

Native color schemes are called `fresh` (grey) and `classic` (blue).